# How to make a computed property of a generic class depend on the class constraints

Tags: swift, generics

I have a protocol and two classes one of which adopts it

```
protocol A { }
class B1 { }
class B2: A { }
```

I would like to have a computed property of a generic class which depends on whether the type adopts `A`. I tried this

```
class C<T> {
    var v: Int { get { return 0 } }
}
extension C where T: A {
    var v: Int { get { return 1 } }
}
```

Now `C<B1>().v` return 0, but `C<B2>().v` complains about ambiguous use of `v`. If I turn `v` into a method it works

```
class D<T> {
    func v() -> Int { return 0 }
}
extension D where T: A {
    func v() -> Int { return 1 }
}
```

Now `C<B1>().v()` returns 0 and `C<B2>().v()` returns 1, as intended.

Why is the getter approach different from the method approach? Can I make the computed property work? I tried

```
class E<T> {
    var v: Int { get { return get() } }
    func get() -> Int { return 0 }
}
extension E where T: A {
    func get() -> Int { return 1 }
}
```

but now `E<B1>().v` and `E<B2>().v` both return 0, i.e. only the unconstrained implementation of `get` is used. Can I "force" the compiler to choose the correct implementaion?

Any thoughts? To me this sounds like a shortfall/bug of Swift, but I do not know enough to be certain. I am using Swift 3 in XCode 8.2.1

UPDATE: I just noticed that even my method solution does not always work and the compiler sometimes decides to go with the more general implementation no matter what. I am not sure what decides this (my actual project is bigger and it is a bit hard to extract a simple example)... So I might be having a more general problem: how to make a property/method of a generic class reliably do different things for different constraints of its type argument(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could  work if you actively check the type of `T` in your computed property like this :

```
class D<T> {
    var v: Int {
        get {
            if let _ = T.self as? A.Type {
                return 1
            } else {
                return 0
            }
        }
    }
}

let c = D<B2>()
print (c.v) // the output is 1
```

Or even shorter :

```
var v: Int { return T.self is A.Type ? 1 : 0  }
```

Comment: This answers my questions as I asked it and covers a lot of cases. Except (and this is what I really needed :-)), when `A` is `ExpressibleByNilLiteral` and my implementation needs to produce a `nil` of type `T`, if `T` is `ExpressibleByNilLiteral`. I will accept your answer, since it answers the question I asked, but would you care to comment on this?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Could you give an example, maybe in another question, for clarity ?

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41492153/how-to-produce-a-nil-of-a-generic-type