# How to produce a nil of a generic type

Tags: swift, generics

I would like to declare a generic class which holds/obtains a variable of type `Any?`, but casts this variable to a given type, when requested. Something like this

```
class A<T> {
    var o: NSObject!
    var k: String!
    var v: T {
        get { return o.value(forKeyPath: k) as! T }
        set { o.setValue(newValue, forKeyPath: k) }
    }
}
```

I would like to this to work so that when `o.value(forKeyPath: k)` is `nil` and `T` can hold a `nil` (it is `ExpressibleByNilLiteral`), `v` returns `nil` (of type `T`). As it is, it crashes because of the `as!`. Is it possible to do this?

An attempted crack at this looks like this (suggested by 
[How to make a computed property of a generic class depend on the class constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41478634/how-to-make-a-computed-property-of-a-generic-class-depend-on-the-class-constrain))

```
class A<T> {
    var o: NSObject!
    var k: String!
    var v: T {
        get { 
            let x = o.value(forKeyPath: k)
            if let E = T.self as? ExpressibleByNilLiteral.Type {
                if let x = x { return x as! T }
                let n: T = <nil of type T> <---- not sure what to put here
                return n
            } else {
                return x as! T 
            }
        }
        set { o.setValue(newValue, forKeyPath: k) }
    }
}
```

but I am not sure how to make it work.

Comment: Could you show how a valid T (conforming to ExpressibleByNilLiteral) would look ?

Comment: The docs are saying "nil has a specific meaning in Swift—the absence of a value. Only the Optional type conforms to ExpressibleByNilLiteral. ExpressibleByNilLiteral conformance for types that use nil for other purposes is discouraged."

Comment: Right, any (and only) `Optional` type will conform to `ExpressibleByNilLiteral`. It only requires `init(nilLiteral: ())`, and we can write `let n: T = E.init(nilLiteral: ()) as! T` (although the comment in the source code for Optional seems to discourage this). Unfortunately, this crashes because `E.init(nilLiteral: ())` is... `nil` and `as!` fails. This works for any protocol that provides some sort of `init` that could be called. But the implementation of `as!` is "entangled" with `ExpressibleByNilLiteral` and the question is how to separate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why, but this actually works

```
func cast<T>(_ v: Any?)->T {
    if let E = T.self as? ExpressibleByNilLiteral.Type {
        if let v = v {
            return v as! T
        } else {
            return E.init(nilLiteral: ()) as! T
        }
    } else {
        return v as! T
    }
}
```

I thought I already tried this and it did not work... Anyway, now we can substitute all `as!` calls with `cast` when we do not want to crash on `nil`, if the type we are casting to can take it, e.g. in the getter of my question.