# How to cast `Any?` to a potentially optional generic type

Tags: swift, generics

I am using generic type erasure and need to get data out of a dictionary and back into its correct type. I use generics to check that the data is correct going into the data structure, then its type is erased.

I have tried looking at some of the options on stack overflow for casting generic optionals but none of them are quite right. I have implemented this in the past but forget how to do it.

```
class Foo {
    private var data = [String: Any?]()

    func getData<STATE:State>(for state: STATE.Type) -> STATE.DATA_TYPE {
        // What do?
    }

    func set<STATE: State>(data: STATE.DATA, for state: STATE.Type) {
        self.stateData[state.stringRepresentation()] = data
    }
}
```

State has `static func stringRepresentation() -> String` which is the key in the dictionary

I want the function to return `Any?` either casted to a nil `STATE.DATA_TYPE` or force cast whatever data is in there to `STATE.DATA_TYPE`. `STATE.DATA_TYPE` can also be optional

Comment: This cannot work, `Any` and generics are two completely different things.

Comment: I mentioned in the example that I have done this before. There is a way to do this. Also I dont understand your comment, generics are types - Any is a type, typecasting is a thing so help me understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to locate the code and the corresponding article that answered my question: [How to produce a nil of a generic type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41492153/how-to-produce-a-nil-of-a-generic-type)

```
func cast<T>(_ v: Any?)->T {
    if let E = T.self as? ExpressibleByNilLiteral.Type {
        if let v = v {
            return v as! T
        } else {
            return E.init(nilLiteral: ()) as! T
        }
    } else {
        return v as! T
    }
}
```

Comment: @EmilioPelaez It should crash in the else case (which will never happen because `func set<STATE: State>(data: STATE.DATA, for state: STATE.Type)`, and the nil case is preceded by a safe check. Why does your response have to be 1. condescending, and 2. not answer the question?